# Enclose multiline elements in fences

Tags: mathml

In trying to learn MathML, I found that the `mfenced` element used [in this tutorial](http://danielscully.co.uk/projects/mathml-guide/groupstyle.php) has been deprecated, so that Firefox no longer supports it.  [This example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Examples/Deriving_the_Quadratic_Formula) in the official MathML documentation simply uses `<mo>(</mo>` and `<mo>)</mo>`, respectively, to surround fractions in parentheses.  When I tried this, I found that the parentheses had normal height and did not stretch to the height of the fraction. Yet the example code had no special attribute to control the parenthesis height, suggesting that it should have adjusted automatically (as it would in LaTeX).  What is missing?  Below is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>MathML in HTML5</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    <math>
      <mo>(</mo>
        <mfrac linethickness="0">
          <mrow><mn>5</mn></mrow>
          <mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow>
        </mfrac>
      <mo>)</mo>
      <mo>=</mo><mn>10</mn>
    </math>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you also need `mrow` to surround the `mo` stuff:

- replace `<mfenced>` with `<mrow><mo>(</mo>`
- replace `</mfenced>` with `<mo>)</mo></mrow>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<math>
    <mrow>
        <mo fence="true" stretchy="true">(</mo)
        ...
        <mo fence="true" stretchy="true">)</mo)
        ...
    </mrow>
</math>
```

See
The MathML Handbook
by Pavi Sandhu
ISBN:1584502495
Charles River Media © 2003 (518
pages)
or else https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/MathML